# Why does LyapunovSolve solve non-standard form?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, control-systems

`LyapunovSolve[A,Q]` solves the equation $A P + P A^T = Q$ for $P$ whereas the standard form ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Stability_for_linear_state_space_models),[lecture notes, p.25](http://control.lth.se/media/Education/EngineeringProgram/FRTN05/2012/lec04_2012.pdf), [linear control systems](http://books.google.de/books?id=VnQhRf2fAAIC&lpg=PA130&ots=RJLnCQrBcM&pg=PA131#v=onepage)) of the Lyapunov function $V(x) = x^T P x$ is obtained by solving $A^T P + P A = -Q$ for $P$. Why is `LyapunovSolve` defined in this way?

Comment: `whereas the standard form of the Lyapunov function` When one says the standard is this and that, it will nice to show a link?

Comment: I added some links. While it may be debatable whether this form can be called standard, it immediately follows from $\dot{V}(x) \leq 0$ and $V(x) = x^T P x$.

Comment: I can't tell now, but just to note that MATLAB also solves the same form as *Mathematica*: http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lyap.html.

Comment: I agree that this is a little strange, as with this definition Q will normally not be positive definite. Also, `RiccatiSolve` solves the form corresponding to what you call "standard form". But why is this important for you?

Comment: I am wondering how the corresponding Lyapunov function is constructed using the matrix resulting from `LyapunovSolve[A,Q]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LyapunovSolve` and `DiscreteLyapunovSolve` solve several equations [Lyapunov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation), [Sylvester](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), Stein, generalized versions, etc., and as such there is no one standard form. Since they are linear solvers their design was based on the precedent set by `LinearSolve`.

For $\dot{x}=A.x$ to be stable, $P=\text{LyapunovSolve}\left[A^{\mathsf{T}},-Q\right]$ has to be positive definite, where the Lyapunov function is $V=x^{\mathsf{T}}.P.x$, $\dot{V}=x^{\mathsf{T}}.Q.x$, and $Q$ is positive definite.

Comment: If we assume $V = x^T P x$ and $\dot{x} = A x$ then $\dot{V} = \dot{x}^T P x + x^T P \dot{x} = (A x)^T P x + x^T P A x = ((A x)^T P + x^T P A) x = (x^T A^T P + x^T P A) x = x^T (A^T P + P A) x \neq x^T (A P + P A^T) x$. Essentially, this irritates me.

Comment: So it looks like  $\text{LyapunovSolve}\left[A^{\mathsf{T}},Q\right]$ is what needs to be solved. (I will update the answer after fully thinking this through. BTW, this is a separate issue from whether Q is on the lhs or rhs.)

Comment: Exactly. While it's clearly possible to use `LyapunovSolve` like that, it is not intuitive. Regarding $Q$, I agree. For stability, $Q$ has to be either positive or negative definite depending on lhs resp. rhs.

Comment: And that goes back to the original point - there is no standard form. Now for stability analysis we have to use the transpose but to obtain the controllability gramian we need not transpose...

Comment: I agree. Thank you.